# What is the VC 11.0 command link option for linking?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, command-line, command-line-arguments

I need to link a library, I got the DLL and the OBJ files. I do *cl /EHsc main.cpp*, now how do I link the obj file for the DLL? I got *glfw3.obj* and *glfw3dll.obj*. Thanks!

Comment: To link against a DLL with MSVC you need an import libary (a `.lib` file), not obj files. (you might still need the .obj files, but they won't link your program to the DLL).

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btw8x58e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) specifies `cl` by default invokes the linker unless `/c` option is used. Try -

```
cl /EHsc main.cpp glfw3.obj glfw3dll.obj
```

Assuming both the object files are in the same location of the main.cpp. If not, you can specify the path using `/LIBPATH`.

Comment: I get *LINK : fatel error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'glfw3.obj'*. What now?

Comment: Linker is unable to find the location of your object files. Try giving full path location instead.